# Intermediate value theorem for $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let's consider the continuous function
$$ f:\mathbb{R}\times [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$$
Such that $f(x,a)>0$ for all $x$ and there exists $x_b$ with $f(x_b,b)\leq 0$.

Then there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x,c)\geq 0$ for all $x$ and a real value $x_c$ with $f(x_c,c)=0$.

Intuitively this seems true, but I woludn't know how to prove it.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the function of minima along the $x$ direction, $g(y) = \inf_x \max(f(x,y), -1)$ will be useful. The trick will be proving it's continuous.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Are you familiar with the infimum function ($\inf$) on sets of real numbers?

Comment: Yes. What I didn't understand is what you were suggesting

Comment: Hmm, maybe that function doesn't help after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition is not true. Take $a=0$ and $b=1$, and let $f$ be given by

$$f(x,y) = 1 - 2x^2y$$

$f(x,a) = 1 > 0$ for all $x$, and at $x_b=1$ we have $f(x_b,b) = -1 < 0$, and $f$ is continuous.

But if $c=0$, we already know $f(x,c) = 1$ so there is no solution to $f(x_c,c)=0$. If $c>0$, then

$$f\left(c^{-1/2},c\right) = -1$$

so it is not true that $f(x,c)\geq 0$ for all $x$.